# How do I hard reset my Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, hard-reset

I have forgotten my password. I have seen some answers to similar questions, but they are all the same. I have tried these, but it always asks me for my password, which is the reason I can't get into my phone. This is also the reason I need to reset my phone.

Comment: What password? Are you referring to the PIN code? Also, what have you tried? Have you tried doing a Factory Reset via Recovery mode? Please edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the phone off, or take the battery out. Put the battery back in and hold VOLUME UP and the HOME key, then the POWER. Hold all three until you see it says recovery mode. When you get to the android, press both volume buttons together and it will show the recovery menu. The rest should be self explanatory.